# Must aviation rental services company do 100-hr inspections?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, 100hr-inspection

We rent our airplane to only certificated, rated pilots. These pilots may rent to increase their XC flight time. They may rent to take a family member sightseeing. In some cases they may rent our airplane and then secure the services of a CFI to pursue an advanced rating, like instrument. It is the choice of the pilot renter.

We’ve been doing 100 hr inspections. Must we?

Comment: In which jurisdiction are you located?

Comment: Oregon. I just saw this response to a previous question:  “If Fly By Knight is going to rent the aircraft to a customer, however, and does not provide the pilot, that aircraft need not have an annual or 100-hour maintenance inspection within the preceding 100 hours of time in service. “